# ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in. with 2 sections

Tags: angular, forms, formgroups

i tried all ways to solve this issue but this error is occurring all time, if i solve this issue for one form, the second section form starts with the same issue. I am no where getting solution to solve this, can anyone help me out please.First 2 fields of this formgroup is not filled with values, and the error comes from the last field of the before section of other group, even though all fields are filled and binded. If i comment the values of error throwing div, jus previous to the commented div throws error.Need in bad help

HTML of first section:

```
 <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Note Field</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Note Field" formControlName="note" maxlength="500" autocomplete="note"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

HTML:

```
  <form [formGroup]="agentCaptiveInfoForm">
      <div class="card-body" >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Agent Number</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Captive Agent Code" name="agentNumber"
                formControlName="agentNumber" allowNumberOnly autocomplete="new-agentNumber" maxlength="10">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">County Code</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Captive Agent County" name="agentCounty"
                formControlName="agentCounty" autocomplete="new-agentCounty" maxlength="50">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">District</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Captive Agent District" name="agentDistrict"
                formControlName="agentDistrict" autocomplete="new-agentDistrict" maxlength="50">  
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Agent Manager</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Captive Agent Manager" name="agentManager"
                formControlName="agentManager" autocomplete="new-agentManager" maxlength="50">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </form>
```

TS:

```
private captiveInfoFormInit() {
   if (!this.groupCode && !this.agentCode) {
    //  Add
      this.agentCaptiveInfoForm = this.FB.group({
        agentNumber: [''],
        agentCounty: [''],
        agentManager: [''],
        agentDistrict: [''],
      })
    } else {
      // Edit
        if(this.agentDetailsList && this.agentDetailsList.captiveInfo) {
          this.agentCaptiveInfoForm = this.FB.group({
            agentNumber: this.agentDetailsList.captiveInfo.captiveAgentNumber?this.agentDetailsList.captiveInfo.captiveAgentNumber:'',
            agentCounty: this.agentDetailsList.captiveInfo.captiveAgentCounty,
            agentManager: this.agentDetailsList.captiveInfo.captiveAgentManager,
            agentDistrict: this.agentDetailsList.captiveInfo.captiveAgentDistrict
          })
        }
   }
    if (this.mode == 1) {
      this.agentCaptiveInfoForm.disable();
      this.isReadOnly = true;
    }
  }
```

In demo there is no error because, i had given values directly, but in my application, `this.agentDetailsList` is obtained after API hit.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pahhht?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: How to trigger `groupInfoForm` function? It looks no one can init agentGroupInfoForm

Comment: yes, groupInfoForm is dynamic binding, hope there is no error with that

Comment: Is this [the result](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gyn3ny?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) you expected?

Comment: Declare and initialise form group for `agentGroupInfoForm`. Like `this.agentGroupInfoForm = new FormGroup({
        agentInGroup: this.FB.array([]),
        agentNotInGroup: this.FB.array([]),
      });`

Comment: @ChunbinLi, thanks a lot, this really helped and saved my day, i actually tried with*ngIf, but somewhere i failed, thanks a ton it worked

Comment: Please post answer, i will vote and accept it

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter this error, you can add `ngIf` into the `formGroup` element to solve it

> ERROR: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one
>   in.

**example**

```
<div [formGroup]="yourFormGroupName" *ngIf="yourFormGroupName" ></div>
```